# having issues with icp ce beta 3, its not booting up. how do I reinstall it

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm having issues with `ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0-beta-3`.
Some containers are unable to start and I'm unable to login ICP.
How do I re-install it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Step 1

- Uninstall ICP - (master node only)

Update **/opt/icp/** to **your** correct directory

`docker run --rm -t -e LICENSE=accept --net=host -v /opt/icp/cluster:/installer/cluster ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0-beta-3 uninstall`

Step 2

- Stop running containers, remove all containers, remove all images - (all nodes)

`docker stop $(docker ps -aq);`

`docker rm $(docker ps -aq);`

`docker rmi $(docker images -q);`

Step 3

- Pull ICP from docker - (master node only)

`docker pull ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0-beta-3;`

Step 4

- Extract ICP - (master node only)

Step 5

Update **/opt/icp/** to **your** correct directory

`docker run -e LICENSE=accept -v /opt/icp:/data ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0-beta-3 cp -r cluster /data;`

Step 6

- Copy the ssh and set the permission - (master node only)

`cp ~/.ssh/master.id_rsa /opt/icp/cluster/ssh_key;`
`chmod 400 /opt/icp/cluster/ssh_key;`

Step 7

- Update your hosts file - (master node only)

Update **/opt/icp/** to **your** correct directory

`/opt/icp/cluster/hosts`

Step 8

- Deploy ICP

`docker run -e LICENSE=accept --net=host -t -v /opt/icp/cluster:/installer/cluster $icpCE install | tee install.log`